# How to tackle the following error in NetworkX?

Tags: python-3.x, plot, dataset, networkx, graphing

I gotta add the nodes and edges from two different lists that I created. Although the nodes are being processed but the edges aren't and thus, the error.

Here's a li'l snippet of my code:
#list3 is the list of the whole dataset

```
listOfRelations = []
listOfNodes = []

for index in range(0, len(list3)):

  #if list3[index].isalpha():

  if list3[index].isdigit():

    listOfNodes.append(list3[index])
  
  else:
    listOfRelations.append(list3[index])

#testing purposes
print(listOfNodes[3])
print(listOfRelations[2])

G.add_nodes_from((listOfNodes))
G.add_edges_from((TupleOfEdges))
```

I also tried to convert the list into a tuple, but that didn't work either :(

> Error: NetworkXError: Edge tuple _hypernym must be a 2-tuple or 3-tuple.

[image]

Comment: Can you include a sample of items in`list3`?  Based on your use of `.isdigit()`, the list is made up of strings but it's not clear what those strings contain, which changes how you might deal with converting them to tuples.

Comment: It's a database that has thousands of entities. The issue that I currently face is how to get the edges in a list of tuples because that's how the networkx function accepts it.

Comment: Yes, but depending on how the items in the `list3` are formatted, that changes how you'd convert them to tuples.  Is `list3` a list of lists and individual node names (for example`[['node1', 'node2'], 'node1', ['3', '4'], '3']`? Or is it a list of just strings (for example `['node1, node2', 'node1', '3, 4', '3']`)?  Or is it in some other format?  Please share an example to clarify.

Comment: what is `G` and `TupleOfEdges` . . . .?  they are both undefined.